# RTMP live streaming support in videoJs and videojs-flash.js for IE <11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video-streaming, video.js, rtmp

I have a new customer request which requires playing live RTMP streaming in Internet Explorer. The customer has a device which has Windows 7 and IE 11 installed but they run a .NET application which launches an IE browser which is supposed to load a lower version of IE.(I'm not sure on the details). I decided to play the stream through the flash player and did a small POC. This is my code,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.1.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <!-- <script>
    videojs.setGlobalOptions({
      flash: {
        swf: 'video-js.swf'
      }
    });
  </script>   -->
</head>

<body>
  <video id="videojs-flash-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay
  preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["flash"] }'>
  <source src="rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" type='rtmp/mp4'>
</video>
<!-- <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-flash/2.1.1/videojs-flash.js"></script>
  <script src="videojs-flashls-source-handler.min.js"></script>  
</body>
<script>
  var player = videojs('videojs-flash-player', {
    flash: {
      swf: 'video-js.swf'
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

This streams fine in IE 11 browser inside the client device but through the .NET application launched, when I load this HTML, I get format not supported issue. I at first used videoJS 7.0 and then found out that they don't support anything lesser than IE 11 but even after using VideoJS 6.0, I'm facing the same issue.

Does videojs-flash.js not support IE < 11? Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Just found out that the client application launches IE 7 internally, does IE 7 support live streaming?

Comment: Any app that uses such old technology has basically opened doors due to number of  vulnerabilities. Also I doubt that IE7 supports any of today's web standards..nobody test it against IE7 yet..

Comment: @bigless is there any way of playing live streaming in IE 7?